# Calculating hours & minutes from entered seconds

Tags: java

I'm new to learning Java and am really enjoying it. My tutor has given me a question and I am trying to figure it out. The question is:  write a program to display an hour and minute from total seconds.

I did begin coding it and I think I got to a certain level, I can now make the program calculated how many total minutes are in the total entered time, or how many total seconds are in the entered time. But I am not able to show them combined meaning 5000 seconds has either 83.44 minutes, or 1.39 hours. But what can I code in order for it to say 1 Hour and 23.44 Minutes. Any insite is helpful. Thank you!

I have attached the code i have written so far.

```java
package HW5820;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class HoursAndMinutes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //write a program to display hour and minute from total seconds

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int seconds=0;

        System.out.println("Enter number of seconds");
        seconds = input.nextInt();

        int min;
        min = seconds/60;

        int hours;
        hours= min/60;


        System.out.println("Your entered time is "+min+" Minutes or, "+hours+" hour");
```

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from the highest level (hours) and work your way down, replacing `seconds` with however many seconds are left over from the previous operation:

```java
int seconds = input.nextInt();

int hours = (int)(seconds / 3600); // Seconds in an hour
seconds = seconds % 3600; // Seconds left over

int minutes = (int)(seconds / 60); // Seconds in a minute
seconds = seconds % 60; // Seconds left over

System.out.println("Your entered time is " + 
                   hours + " hours, " + 
                   minutes + " minutes, and " + 
                   seconds + " seconds.");
```

As a further improvement, you can eliminate magic numbers by assigning them to well-named variables, i.e. :

```java
int SECONDS_IN_HOUR = 3600;
int SECONDS_IN_MINUTE = 60;
```

And then use those in your operations:

```java
int hours = (int)(seconds / SECONDS_IN_HOUR);
seconds = seconds % SECONDS_IN_HOUR; // Seconds left over

int minutes = (int)(seconds / SECONDS_IN_MINUTE);
seconds = seconds % SECONDS_IN_MINUTE; // Seconds left over
```

Comment: Thank you for the info I will try this out.

Comment: @FahimAlamShakie If this answers your question, be sure to mark it as the accepted answer so others know that your question has been answered. :)